# how to boot from linux mini iso to first hard drive

Tags: iso, bootloader

### My Problem

I'd like to know how to boot in to first hard drive when using a custom txt.cfg for isolinux while using the official [minimal Iso from Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD).

I'm asking because VirtualBox has a bug and does not reject the iso when installation is finished

```
default installen
label installde
menu label ^Install in German
menu default
kernel linux
append vga=788 initrd=initrd.gz -- quiet  -- priority=critical locale=de_DE     url=http://webserver.com/folder/preseed.cfg 
label installen
menu label ^install in English
kernel linux
append vga=788 initrd=initrd.gz -- quiet  -- priority=critical locale=en_US url=http://http://webserver.com/folder/preseed.cfg
```

#### How is the correct code for this one?

```
label bootfromhd
menu label ^boot from first hard drive
kernel linux
appendinitrd  (hd0,1)/initrd.img
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is solving the issue

```
label hd
menu label ^Boot from first hard disk
localboot 0x80
```